# Locating class using enums in base class

Tags: java, selenium, oop, enums

Hi I have the code like this:

in every PageClass:

```
public void goToParticularTableSection(TableSectionDraggablePage tableSectionDraggablePage){
    switch (tableSectionDraggablePage) {
        case DefaultFunctionality:
            clickOnElement(defaultFunctionalityTableHeader);
            break;
        case ConstrainMovement:
            clickOnElement(constraintMovementTableHeader);
            break;
        ...
    }
    TestLogger.log.info(tableSectionDraggablePage + " clicked");
}
```

For every PageClass I have another class with enums:

```
public enum TableSectionDraggablePage {
    DefaultFunctionality,
    ConstrainMovement,
    ...
}
```

How to move goToParticularTableSection method into Base class and have the common use of this method in every PageClass what allows me avoid code duplication in every page class?

Comment: What do you mean by _how to move_?  What is stopping you from refactoring the code?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: This can’t be answered without knowing more about the classes.  Is `clickOnElement` inherited from the base class?  Does each page class have its own unique set of actions and its own unique set of headers?

Comment: Yes clickOnElement is inherited and each page class have its own unique set of actions

Answer (score 0):

One idea might be defining some getters in `PageClass` like `getDefaultFunctionality(), getConstrainMovement()` etc. and then redesign the `enum` like this:

```
public enum TableSectionDraggablePage {
 DefaultFunctionality, 
 defaultFunctionalityTableHeader,
 ConstrainMovement,
 constraintMovementTableHeader,
 ...

 TableSectionDraggablePage(PageClass pageClass) {
   this.DefaultFunctionality = pageClass.getDefaultFunctionality();
   this.defaultFunctionalityTableHeader = pageClass.getDefaultFunctionalityTableHeader();
   ...
 }
}
```

Then move `goToParticularTableSection(TableSectionDraggablePage)` to `BaseClass`.

Then just call the method from PageClass like this:

```
super.goToParticularTableSection(new TableSectionDraggablePage(this));
```

Comment: I cannot define in here ->TableSectionDraggablePage(PageClass pageClass) a class - java does not allow..